# Application (.exe) not starting when other application (.exe) is running

Tags: vb.net, autodesk-inventor

I've created a vb project in which I've made my first application (.exe).
For my second project I wanted to use the same code and forms as in the first project - so I've copied the whole folder of the first project and I've made the second application (.exe).
When I run the first application (.exe) it works like a charm - but when I try to run the second application - it doesn't start.
The second application starts when I close the first application (and vice versa).
It seems like Windows (Win 7) sees both applications as the same one.

After I've copied the first project to create the second project - I've renamed the second project an all the folders inside. I've also changed all the Assembly Information in the second project (I'am using Visual Basic 2010 Express).
Both applications have diffrent names (also diffrent names for processes) in Task Manager (Win 7).

How can I run both of those applications at the same time ?

What do I need to change in order to fix this problem?

Comment: There would be a GUID somewhere identifying the application and the fact that you used the same project means that both apps have the same GUID.  I'm not 100% sure where that would be or whether it would be safe to change it manually without knowing exactly what you were doing.

Comment: Instead, I would recommend creating a new project and then using the 'Add -> Existing Item' feature to import existing forms, etc, from the old project into the new one.  That way, you have a new application with all the old functionality.

Comment: It was GUID problem. I've generated a new GUID and pasted it to Assembly Information. It fixed the problem. Thaks to you all above.
I've made my self a simple GUID generator (simple form with button) with below code:

Dim oGuid As String = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

Comment: You can also create a new project and copy GUID from Assembly Information.

Comment: I'm not sure about VB 2010 Express but VS 2017 has a GUID generator built in on the Tools menu.  I'm fairly certain that goes back a few versions at least. Is there a reason that you're still using VB 2010 Express when you've been able to get VS Community for free for a number of years now?

Comment: @jmcilhinney imo we all want to upgrade but although i have a powerful laptop, 2013 is much faster than the others :) it's like Win7 vs Win8 (which had more features) :P

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes, VB 2010 Express has built in GUID generator. When it comes to using a newer version - unfortunately they do not work on my PC at work. I don't know what is the issue exactly. Nonetheless I'm happy with the 2010 Express version. Where can I find a English version of VB 2010 Express? I'm using German version for over a year (I could only find that version and It's weird).